# How to use an AWS federated token with AWS iOS SDK 2.0

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

I've checked the AWS docs, and everything there points to Cognito, can't find how to just use an AccessKeyId and a SecretAccessKey.

All user management and authentication takes place on the server.  There's a long access policy that the server determines based on specific user permissions, and then the server generates a temporary FederationToken with that policy and passes that to the iOS app to use.

Does anyone have a code sample of how to use that passed Federated user in iOS to upload an item to s3?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement your credentials provider by conforming to `AWSCredentialsProvider`. Take a look at the implementations of `AWSWebIdentityCredentialsProvider` and `AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider` as examples. This credentials provider should:

- Retrieve the access key, secret key, and session key from your server.
- Persist them locally until they expire.
- Return the credentials when requested.
- Re-retrieve them from your server if they are expired.
- Calling `- refresh` also should initiate the credentials refreshing process.